# How to create Dask DataFrame from a list of urls?

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have a list of the URLs, and I'd love to read them to the dask data frame
at once, but it looks like `read_csv` can't use an asterisk for `http`. Is there any way to achieve that?

Here is an example:

```
link = 'http://web.mta.info/developers/'

data = [     'data/nyct/turnstile/turnstile_170128.txt',
                        'data/nyct/turnstile/turnstile_170121.txt',
                        'data/nyct/turnstile/turnstile_170114.txt',
                        'data/nyct/turnstile/turnstile_170107.txt' 
        ]
```

and what I want is

`df = dd.read_csv('XXXX*X')`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using [dask.delayed](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/delayed.html) to turn each of your urls into a lazy pandas dataframe and then use [dask.dataframe.from_delayed](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.from_delayed)  to turn those lazy values into a full dask dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import dask
import dask.dataframe as dd

dfs = [dask.delayed(pd.read_csv)(url) for url in urls]

df = dd.from_delayed(dfs)
```

This will read *one* of your links immediately in order to figure out metadata (column, dtypes).  If you know these dtypes and links ahead of time then you can avoid this by passing a sample empty dataframe to `dd.from_delayed(..., meta=sample_df)`

See also: http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/delayed-collections.html