# What is the fastest way to make a DataFrame from a list?

Tags: python, pandas

So basically im trying to transform a list into a DataFrame.

Here are the two ways of doing it that I am trying, but I cannot come up to a good performance benchmark.

```py
import pandas as pd

mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
names = ["name","name","name","name","name","name"]

# Way 1
pd.DataFrame([mylist], columns=names)

# Way 2
pd.DataFrame.from_records([mylist], columns=names)
```

I also tried dask but I did not find anything that could work for me.

Comment: Calling `pd.DataFrame` is marginally faster. What is the scale of data here? Why is performance so important?

Comment: Hmm, like milions of columns. I am looking for bottlenecks in my code and trying to make all the code faster overall.

Comment: If you are trying to optimize performance of `pd.DataFrame` I see struggles down the line.. possibly Pandas as a framework will not be efficient for your needs. Profile your code to confirm it's *actually* your bottleneck.

Comment: I had similar issues, and I  would often try to replace all strings with ints using .cat or creating a dict. Again as jpp said pandas isn't the program for big data, save it as a csv and dump it into a SQL dB, clean it and then export the data you need for analysis.

Comment: also i'm no expert but would delcaring the dtypes speed this up? especially if you have date times declaring the format is much better for pandas

Comment: Thanks! I will try this approach!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so I just made up an example with 10 columns and random integers in the range of 1 Million values in those, i got the maximum result very quickly. Does this give you maybe a start to work with dask? They proposed the approach [here](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/delayed-collections.html) which is also related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43104302/how-to-create-dask-dataframe-from-a-list-of-urls).

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.delayed import delayed
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create List with random integers
list_large = [np.random.random_sample(int(1e6))*i for i in range(10)]

# Convert it to dask dataframe
dfs = [delayed(pd.DataFrame)(i) for i in list_large]
df = dd.from_delayed(dfs)

# Calculate Maximum
max = df.max().compute()
```